# jquery ui autocomplete source from json file

Tags: php, jquery

I can incorporate jquery ui autocomplete with source from database. How, I am trying to get the source from a prepared json file, the content is like this:-

```
{"data":[{"id":"1","country_name_en":"USA","country_name_hk":"\u7f8e\u570b"},{"id":"2","country_name_en":"China","country_name_hk":"\u4e2d\u570b"},{"id":"3","country_name_en":"British","country_name_hk":"\u82f1\u570b"}]}
```

I tried to modify the jquery codes as follow:-

```
<script>
$( "#country" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request,response) {
      $.getJSON('../../database/country.json',{id: data.id},function(data){
            alert(data);
      })
    }
});
</script>
```

but I think I do not written the format correctly. How shall I improve the way to extract the data from the json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autocomplete won't show anything until you tell it to do so by calling the `response` function passed to your source method with the allowed autocomplete values. So you should do something like this:

```
$( "#country" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request,response) {
        $.getJSON('../../database/country.json',{id: data.id},function(data){
            var choices = [];
            for(var i=0;i<data.data.length;i++) {
                choices.push(data.data[i].country_name_en);
            }
            response(choices);
        })
    }
});
```

Also just a tip, you're going to confuse yourself by naming everything "data".

Answer (score 0):

Ajax can be used for this refer this [article](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) which list countries from  geonames.org(contains huge list country,state,regions). This will help you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from json try this..

```
$("#country").autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response) {
       $.getJSON('../../database/country.json', { id: data.id }, function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
               alert(value.country_name_en); // json data
          });
       });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you need to call the autocomplete callback from the ajax success handler.

```
$(function() {
    $("#country").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON('country.json', {
                id : 1
            }, function(data) {
                var list = $.map(data.data, function(item, index) {
                    return {
                        id : item.id,
                        label : item.country_name_en
                    };
                });
                response(list);
            })
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nzsFW6nCyt4d7JWVe82w?p=preview)